# Understanding Instantiation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, instantiation

I’m currently trying to learn Objective-C by reading books and online tutorials, also referring to the Apple documentation but some things just don’t click.  I have a question about classes, I have been using the NSString for a while now without putting too much attention on how it is used.

I was under the impression that in order for someone to be able to use a method from a certain class in Objective-C you first needed to instantiate it, something like…

```
ClasssName *varName = [[ClassName alloc]init];
```

Then  you would call methods like...

```
[varName someMethod];
```

But looking at how the NSString is used I’m now I little confused, for instance here is how we would normally use it...

```
NSString *someString = @"some text here";
[someString stringByAppendingFormat:  @"some text = %d", 3];
```

Following what I have read about classes we would need to do something like the following instead.

```
NSString *someString  =  [[NSString alloc]initWithString: @"some text here"];
[someString stringByAppendingFormat:  @"some text = %d", 3];
```

Can someone explain why some classes do not require instantiation before using its methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objective-C knows some abbreviations that are called *literals*. The compiler is aware of the special notation. A string literal is compiled into the binary and exits throughout the lifetime of an app.

For most cases it will behave like an object created on runtime.

- if two literals are identical, only one object will be created and live forever
- if you create `NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"My String"];` with `@"My String"` being used as a literal before, also `string` can point to it.

Since Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0 Objective-C knows some [more literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). But in contrast to string literals these literals are created during runtime through convenient initializers.

---

Note that

```
[someString stringByAppendingFormat:  @"some text = %d", 3];
```

does not change someString. It returns a new string object.

```
NSString *newString = [someString stringByAppendingFormat:  @"some text = %d", 3];
```

Comment: Only string literals are compiled into the binary. The new object literals (NSNumbers, dictionaries and arrays) create instances that are build during runtime using conventional convenience constructors.

Comment: Removal of identical instances is an optimization not guaranteed by the compiler. Two compilation units might get different instances.

Comment: The compiler does not decide to convert normal to literal instantiation.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, as stated above, it is a short notation that the compiler knows about and has nothing to do with standard OOP practices, correct?
I was looking at the link provided by vikingosegundo and it looks like Apple is constantly adding new features to improve and increase productivity and I believe that this is what makes it hard for a newbie to understand some concepts since they have nothing to do with standard programming practices but it the same time it make the coding process faster for people with more experience.

Comment: string literas have been around for quite a while. So you should stumble upon it in practical any documentation/tutorial. And most languages change and get augmented over time. C++0x11, Java became open source, python even became backward incompatible… So informing oneself about additions and changes in "best practice" belongs to the daily basic business of developers.

Comment: @fs_tigre - you could say that literals have "nothing to do with standard OOP" but only because they have everything to do with "standard programming". Literals for primitive types; integers, characters, etc.; are of course fundamental. However literals for constructed types exist in most, if not all, programming languages. In C `"a string"` is a literal for an array of characters, languages with records have literal records etc., all the way back to FORTRAN where there are literal arrays. A literal is just a value (primitive or constructed) which is written down in full rather than computed.

Comment: I guess I got confused because I was under the impression that literals were some sort of data-type not a class, in this case NSString class. I believe in C++ a literal string is define as follow. -  string varName = "some text"; -  but again string is the data-type not a class.  Sorry if my confusion doesn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 5):

The `@"Text"` syntax gives you an autoreleased string back, it can be thought of as a shorthand.

when you write

```
[[NSString alloc]initWithString: @”some text here”];
```

you conceptually create an autoreleased string with `@”some text here”` and then you create a retained new string with `initWithString`.

Comment: Actually it's not autoreleased. It just never deallocates, no matter how many release messages it receives.

Comment: What @NikolaiRuhe says is true, but it's also just an implementation detail. You should always treat strings returned from the `@""` notation as autoreleased.

Comment: A string literal is *immortal* not *autoreleased*. Consider *ownership* rather than *autoreleased*. You *own* an object only if either if ownership was passed to you or you take it (`retain`, assign to a `strong`, etc.). You are responsible for relinquishing your ownership (`release`, hand ownership to another, etc.). A string literal is immortal and can be treated *either* as owned *or* not; when returning a string literal as an owned reference you *do not need* to take ownership before doing so, as you would if it was autoreleased. In general: use ARC, think ownership, forget autorelease...